# How can I make the first letter push itself into the paragraph like a newspaper style

Tags: html, css

I created some CSS to handle the first letter in a paragraph too look bigger,

How can I make the first letter push itself down and to the left so it will not be higher than the line itself and indent the other lines to the right if needed? (see attached image)

[image]

```css
.text-article {
  color: #000;
}

.text-article:first-letter {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-size: 6rem;
  line-height: 10px;
  line-height: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-article">
We the People is a section of the whitehouse.gov website, launched September 22, 2011,[1] for petitioning the current administration's policy experts. Petitions that meet a certain threshold of signatures are most of the time reviewed by officials in the Administration and official responses are then issued, but not always, as outlined in the Criticism section.[1] Criminal justice proceedings in the United States are not subject to White House website petitions. In fact, no real processes of the federal government are subject to these White House website petitions; they are a public relations device for the present administration which permits citizens to express themselves. On August 23, 2012, the White House Director of Digital Strategy Macon Phillips released the source code for the platform.[2] The source code is available on GitHub, and lists both public domain status as a work of the U.S. federal government and licensing under the GPL v2.[3]
</div>
```

Comment: what do you need ? all first letter of all lines bigger ?

Comment: These are called "drop caps".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop-caps using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643684/drop-caps-using-css)

Comment: Thank you torazaburo - good to know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `float:left` to get the first letter to move down and push the other lines out of the way. You'll also need to adjust the `line-height` to make it a bit larger -- I used `40px`/`4rem`.

```css
.text-article {
    color: #000;
}
.text-article:first-letter {
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-size: 6rem;
    line-height: 40px;
    line-height: 4rem;
    height:4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-article">
We the People is a section of the whitehouse.gov website, launched September 22, 2011,[1] for petitioning the current administration's policy experts. Petitions that meet a certain threshold of signatures are most of the time reviewed by officials in the Administration and official responses are then issued, but not always, as outlined in the Criticism section.[1] Criminal justice proceedings in the United States are not subject to White House website petitions. In fact, no real processes of the federal government are subject to these White House website petitions; they are a public relations device for the present administration which permits citizens to express themselves. On August 23, 2012, the White House Director of Digital Strategy Macon Phillips released the source code for the platform.[2] The source code is available on GitHub, and lists both public domain status as a work of the U.S. federal government and licensing under the GPL v2.[3]
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Carter, I'm a little CSS retarded sometimes :-)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is using [`initial-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial-letter) CSS property.

```css
.text-article:first-letter {
  color: red;
  initial-letter: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-article">
We the People is a section of the whitehouse.gov website, launched September 22, 2011,[1] for petitioning the current administration's policy experts. Petitions that meet a certain threshold of signatures are most of the time reviewed by officials in the Administration and official responses are then issued, but not always, as outlined in the Criticism section.[1] Criminal justice proceedings in the United States are not subject to White House website petitions. In fact, no real processes of the federal government are subject to these White House website petitions; they are a public relations device for the present administration which permits citizens to express themselves. On August 23, 2012, the White House Director of Digital Strategy Macon Phillips released the source code for the platform.[2] The source code is available on GitHub, and lists both public domain status as a work of the U.S. federal government and licensing under the GPL v2.[3]
</div>
```