# react-native nested text with differnt fontsizes (initial, first letter)

Tags: text, font-size, react-native

I currently write a news reader app in react-native and want to style the first letter of an article as an initial, like below:

[image: An example of an initial]

For my first attempt I use the nested text aproach. The code is attached below. And this is my current result:

[image: Result with react-native]

The code in the render function:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>
        <Text style={styles.initial}>W</Text>
        <Text>
            elcome to React Native! To get started, edit index.android.js To get started, edit index.android.js To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
    </Text>
</View>
```

My stylesheet:

```
const fontSize = 14;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    initial: {
        fontSize: fontSize * 2,            
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: fontSize,
        color: '#333333',
    },
});
```

**My Question:**
How can I style my first char to get a pretty initial?

**Environment**

- react: 16.0.0-alpha.6
- react-native: 0.44.2
- Android 6.0 on an emulated Nexus 5

Answer (score 4):

you can try in this way too, add the regular style for parent Text element and required style for the "W" text child element.

```
export default class DemoProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        *<Text>
          <Text style={[styles.textCommon, styles.firstLetter]}>W</Text>
        elcome</Text>*
      </View>
    );
  }
}


  text: {
        fontSize: fontSize,
        color: '#333333',
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it:

```
export default class DemoProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={[styles.textCommon, styles.firstLetter]}>W</Text>
        <Text>elcome</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  textCommon: {
    color: '#333333',
  },
  firstLetter: {
    fontSize: 23,
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
I've tried it. For a single word it would be ok. But if you add whole paragraph after 'elcome' it has not the desired effect.

Comment: Tried with the text "Welcome my dear friend, how are you?" Still works for me. Do you mean a new line paragraph?

Comment: Yes I mean a paragraph with many linebreaks. Look at my first [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj4KM.png) for a better impress. 
With this aproach comes closer:  
In the container style: `justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start',`
But it's not perfect ;)
The following paragraph should flow around the 'W'.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this issue in 2023, I didn't find any good solution for this. So I implemented it myself with a dedicated component.
Hopefully we will get better solution just like `::first-letter` has in `CSS`

I am using `twrnc` but you can easily swap the style implementation with what you are using.

In short what happening here is that when given a text I calculate the width of the layout and than get the first and second sentences from it, taking into consideration the first character length, when i'm done getting those I calculate the reset of the text data.

```
interface TextWithFirstLetterSpanProps extends ViewProps {
  text: string;
  fontSize?: number;
  lineHeight?: number;
}
export default function ({
  text,
  fontSize = 17,
  lineHeight = 1.4,
  ...viewProps
}: TextWithFirstLetterSpanProps) {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const onLayout = (event: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
    const { width } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    setWidth(width);
  };
  const firstLetter = useMemo(() => text.charAt(0), [text]);
  const { firstSentence, secondSentence, rest } = useMemo(() => {
    let sentenceBuffer = '';
    const widthWithoutFirstLetter = width - fontSize * 2;
    let secondSentence = '';
    let rest = '';
    const words = text.split(' ');
    words[0] = words[0].slice(1);
    let firstSentence = '';
    while (words.length > 0) {
      const word = words.shift() ?? '';
      if (firstSentence && secondSentence) {
        rest += ` ${word}`;
        continue;
      }
      if (((sentenceBuffer.length + word.length) * fontSize) / 2 < widthWithoutFirstLetter) {
        sentenceBuffer += ` ${word}`;
      } else {
        if (firstSentence === '') {
          firstSentence = sentenceBuffer;
        } else if (secondSentence === '') {
          secondSentence = sentenceBuffer;
        } else {
          rest += `${sentenceBuffer}`;
        }
        sentenceBuffer = word;
      }
    }

    return {
      firstSentence,
      secondSentence,
      rest,
    };
  }, [text, width]);

  return (
    <View onLayout={onLayout} {...viewProps}>
      <View style={tw.style(`flex flex-row text-base gap-[0.3]`)}>
        <Text
          style={tw.style(`font-tiemposHeadline uppercase mt-1`, {
            fontSize: fontSize * 2 * lineHeight,
            lineHeight: fontSize * 2 * lineHeight,
          })}
        >
          {firstLetter}
        </Text>
        <View>
          <Text
            style={tw.style({
              fontSize: fontSize,
              lineHeight: fontSize * lineHeight,
            })}
          >
            {firstSentence}
          </Text>
          <Text
            style={tw.style({
              fontSize: fontSize,
              lineHeight: fontSize * lineHeight,
            })}
          >
            {secondSentence}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <Text
        style={tw.style({
          fontSize: fontSize,
          lineHeight: fontSize * lineHeight,
        })}
      >
        {rest}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I think this is the best solution for your question

[How can I make the first letter push itself into the paragraph like a newspaper style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563012/how-can-i-make-the-first-letter-push-itself-into-the-paragraph-like-a-newspaper/34563048)?

just convert css to react-style

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)
How do you convert `.text-article:first-letter` to react-native?