# How to apply drop cap styles to pseudo-element content

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, drop-cap

I have a Q&A page in my blog, and I wanted to make it so the question starts with a large question mark, and the answer with a large exclamation mark, that is a drop cap. Such effect is easy to achieve with `::first-letter` pseudo-element and `initial-letter` property, like it was demonstrated in another question asked here ([Drop-caps using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643684/drop-caps-using-css)), but the problem is that **question mark and exclamation mark are not letters, therefore this approach does not work for them**. Is there an alternative solution for this?

My makeshift solution is to use the `::before` pseudo-class, but it only makes the question mark or exclamation mark bigger, without making it a drop cap.

I wanted to know if there is a way to make the question mark sink into the paragraph, and not just be bigger.

```css
.question::before {
  content: '?';
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">I have a Q&A page in my blog, and I wanted to make it so the question starts with a large question mark, and the answer with a large exclamation mark, that is a drop cap. Such effect is easy to achieve with `::first-letter` pseudo-element and `initial-letter` property, but the problem is that question mark and exclamation mark are not letters, therefore these approach does not work for them. Is there an alternative solution for this?</div>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that this should really be considered a duplicate; this asks about a special case that the other does not address, and whose answers do not work for this case.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You're right. Isherwood closed it after I suggested a duplicate, but looking closer the cases are only similar, not the same. I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the few remaining valid use cases for floats. You can reduce bottom gap by shrinking line-height.

For fun and easier maintenance I've pulled the drop character value from a data attribute on the paragraph element. This allows distinct characters without extra CSS. I've also made your selector more generic, leveraging the same attribute. Reusability should be a goal in all code.

```css
[data-dropchar]::before {
  content: attr(data-dropchar);
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p data-dropchar="?">I have a Q&A page in my blog, and I wanted to make it so the question starts with a large question mark, and the answer with a large exclamation mark, that is a drop cap. Such effect is easy to achieve with `::first-letter` pseudo element and `initial-letter` property, but the problem is that question mark and exclamation mark are not letters, therefore these approach does not work for them. Is there an alternative solution for this?</p>

<p data-dropchar="I">I have a Q&A page in my blog, and I wanted to make it so the question starts with a large question mark, and the answer with a large exclamation mark, that is a drop cap. Such effect is easy to achieve with `::first-letter` pseudo element and `initial-letter` property, but the problem is that question mark and exclamation mark are not letters, therefore these approach does not work for them. Is there an alternative solution for this?</p>
```